# error After migrating my ArcGIS Explorer prject to a 64 bits machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio, arcgis, esri

I recently migrated my project to a 64 bits machine, how ever when i try to build the proejct in visual studio 2010, I get the error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Explorer/bin/ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**

Any body has an idea what could be the solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I managed to fix this by adding an exe file to the my list of startup exectubales, but I guess that this was a special case and can't be generalized